# Merge records with identical ID in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, merge, table, summarizing

I need to merge records with the same PIN, and populate the null fields with values if they exist. The highlighted ones in the image are what I'm talking about.

This is just a test run; for the final product I will have 2,000+ records and 14 additional fields, instead of 4.

Does anyone know a good workflow to accomplish this?

If my description is not clear enough, this is what I need.

No more duplicate records, each parcel should have one record, and PIN 35.00071.01 (the first highlighted record) should read:

P12_acres: 79 | P12_amount: 10666 | P17_acres: 160 | P17_amount: 24000

[image: Collapse records with same PIN]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) tool for this, it will aggregate records in a table by certain fields you specify while calculating statistics (Max, Min, Sum, etc.) for the values in the other fields. In your case you would run it on that layer using PIN as the CASE field, and calculating the MAX value for each of the other 4 fields you're interested in (_acres and _amounts). That will give the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I had just used that tool for the first time to produce those fields in separate shapefiles. I didn't even think to use it again.

Comment: @BrandonG. You're welcome. That tool is really handy for all sorts of things you might normally export your data to Excel or whatever to do.